# Making a deck of cards

Tags: string, loops, replace, integer

Everything runs smoothly until I want to replace `11` of "spades" with `Jack` of "spades". I want the program to print `Ace`, `Jack`, `Queen` and `King` instead of `1`, `11`, `12`, `13`, `14` respectively. Here's the code so far in its entirety, my attempt at making `11` appear as `Jack` is in the `def show()` function. The problem is that when I run the program it simply doesn't recognize the code. Everything runs as it should except `11` isn't `Jack`, it's still `11`.

```
 if c in self.cards == 11:
                self.cards.replace(Card(v, "Jack "))
           
import random
class Card(object):
    def __init__(self, colour, value):
        self.colour = colour
        self.value = value


    def show(self):
        print("{} of {}".format(self.value, self.colour))


class deck(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.cards = []
        self.domain()
    def domain(self):
        for s in ["Spades", "Hearts", "Diamonds", "Clubs"]:
            for v in range(1, 14):
                 self.cards.append(Card(s, v))
#makes the card by attributing colour and value to each card^
    # NOTE: notice the for loops and the s, v variables^
    def show(self):
        for c in self.cards:
            c.show()
            if c in self.cards == 11:
                self.cards.replace(Card(v, "Jack "))
            if self.cards == 1:
                self.cards.replace(Card(v, "Ace "))

    def shuffle(self):
        for i in range(len(self.cards) -1, 0, -1):
            r = random.randint(0, i)
            self.cards[i], self.cards[r] = self.cards[r], self.cards[i]

#prints the card individually, or shows the card^
    def draw(self):
        return self.cards.pop()

class Player(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.hand = []

    def draw(self, deck):
        self.hand.append(deck.draw())
        return self

    def show_hand(self):
        for card in self.hand:
            card.show()

player = Player("Jacob")

deck = deck()
deck.show()
```

Comment: Hi, you can add a language tag to make it more attractive to potential experts.

Comment: You don't specify the language, as Light mentioned.  You should update the question with the language in the title or description, along with a tag for the correct language.